# Adding Fragments to an Activity That's Using a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm building an Android app which utilizes the Navigation Drawer UI pattern for top-level navigation. In order to facilitate this, I created a custom `Activity` (called `DrawerActivity`) which automatically initializes the `DrawerLayout`. For each `DrawerActivity's` "content" view, I want to use `Fragments`.

By default, every `DrawerActivity` will inflate the following layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_drawerLayout"
    tools:context=".activities.DrawerActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@color/drawer_background" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'm also going to support various sized tablets with my app, so I require the capability to dynamically load `Fragments` into the main "content" view of the layout. Not a problem, I already know how to initialize a `FragmentTransaction` to take care of that for me.

However, the `DrawerLayout` only seems to work properly when I have one "content" widget, commonly placeheld by a `FrameLayout`. If I want to replace the `FrameLayout` with a `Fragment`, I'd simply build a `FragmentTransaction` and go from there. However, I'd like to automatically inflate two or more `Fragments` if necessary (depending on if the user is using a tablet or not).

**My Question:** What would be the "best" way to build my UI using `Fragments`, all while supporting the Navigation Drawer UI pattern? Should I instead use an `<include />` tag for the `DrawerActivity's` "content" view (which would automatically choose the correct layout required based on orientation and screen size), or should I load in the `Fragments` myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by building building a separate layout with the same name and placing it in the 'res/layout-sw600dp' directory:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_drawerLayout"
    tools:context=".activities.DrawerActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientaion="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_start"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:weight="1" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_end"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@color/drawer_background" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then you can programmatically check for the content_container id and load the appropriate fragments based on if it exists or not.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even thought of doing it this way. Makes a lot more sense! Thanks a bunch!